# Quisiera saber como puedo desarrollar el condicional, quiero que un elemento se aparesca y biseversa cuando presione un boton

Tags: funciones, condiciones, eventos

//El plan esque cuando yo precione el boton "img" el elemento "menu_01" aparezca y cuando vuelva a presionar pase lo contrario, porcierto como se dieron cuenta llevo poco haciendo codigo.

```
  window.onload = function(){
    const objs = document.getElementById("menu_01"); 
    objs.addEventListener("click", ocultarElemento);

    function ocultarElemento(){
        if (objs.click){
            document.getElementById("menu_01").style.display = "block";
  
        }
      } 
      
  }
```

Comment: Hola  GUILLE'S, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código de tu html?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amigo puedes utilizar una variable **booleana** para almacenar el estado de **true** o **false** y luego darle un estilo cuando se muestre.
tambien puedes cambiar el texto utilizando la propiedad **innerHTML** .
aquí te dejo un ejemplo espero que te sirva gracias :

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu_01"); 
    const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle_button");
    let visible = true;

    toggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleElemento);

    function toggleElemento(){
        if (visible === undefined) {
            visible = false;
        } 
        else {
            visible = !visible;
        }
        if (visible) {
            menu.style.display = "block";
            toggleButton.innerHTML = "Presione para ocultar";
        } else {
            menu.style.display = "none";
            toggleButton.innerHTML = "Presione para mostrar";
        }
    } 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_01">
      <p>Este es el elemento que deseas ocultar o mostrar</p>
</div>
<button id="toggle_button"> Presiona para ocultar </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función toggle para lista de clases, que hace lo siguiente

- Si el elemento tiene la clase, se la quita
- Si no la tiene se la agrega

*(Es como la lógica de un interruptor)*

Con esto te ahorras de ocupar una variable booleana que guarde el estado y todo el rollo.

Entonces solo tienes que crear clases CSS acorde a tus necesidades.

Ejemplo:

```js
const img_btn = document.getElementById("img_btn");
const menu =  document.getElementById("menu_01");


img_btn.addEventListener("click", e=>{    
 menu.classList.toggle("ocultar");
 img_btn.classList.toggle("MostrarText")
});
```

```css
.ocultar{
  visibility:hidden;
}

#img_btn:after {
   content:'Ocultar'
}

#img_btn.MostrarText:after {
   content:'Mostrar'
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_01">Soy un menu</div>
<button id="img_btn"></button>
```